# How to PATCH a field of an object to null explicitly by a PATCH RESTful API

Tags: rest, patch

I've got a question about how to PATCH a field of an object to null explicitly by a PATCH RESTful API. Here's an exmple.

#### Step 1. Create a recurring meeting which occurs every day

**Request**

```
POST /meetings
{
    "topic": "Daily meeting",
    "start": "2023-09-13T10:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-09-13T10:30:00Z",
    "recurrence": "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "id": "495e0ee246fa4b149cc6b8a331dcb661"
    "topic": "Daily meeting",
    "start": "2023-09-13T10:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-09-13T10:30:00Z",
    "recurrence": "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
}
```

#### Step 2. Update the topic by PATCH

The API behaves as expected.

**Request**

```
PATCH /meetings/495e0ee246fa4b149cc6b8a331dcb661
{
    "topic": "Daily scrum meeting"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "id": "495e0ee246fa4b149cc6b8a331dcb661"
    "topic": "Daily scrum meeting",
    "start": "2023-09-13T10:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-09-13T10:30:00Z",
    "recurrence": "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
}
```

#### Step 3. Update the topic and change the meeting from recurring to non-recurring by PATCH

The `recurrence` is expected to be null after the patch, but actually it's not changed.

**Request**

```
PATCH /meetings/495e0ee246fa4b149cc6b8a331dcb661
{
    "topic": "Daily meeting",
    "recurrence": null
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "id": "495e0ee246fa4b149cc6b8a331dcb661"
    "topic": "Daily meeting",
    "start": "2023-09-13T10:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-09-13T10:30:00Z",
    "recurrence": "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
}
```

The problem is, when it comes to the Spring controller method below, `recurrence` is `null` in both step 2 and step 3, regardless of whether "recurrence" is absent (step 2) or "recurrence" is null explicitly (step 3).

What I want is, "schedulerVO.recurrence has been specified null explicitly" can be detected so that the meeting can be changed from recurring to non-recurring.

So, how can I distinguish the two situations?

```java
public class SchedulerVO {
    private String topic;
    private String start;
    private String end;
    private String recurrence;
    // Setters & getters ...
}

public class MeetingVO extends SchedulerVO {
    private String id;
    private String topic;
    private String start;
    private String end;
    private String recurrence;
    // Setters & getters ...
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class MeetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/meetings/{meetingId}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public MeetingVO patchMeeting(@PathVariable("meetingId") String meetingId,
            @RequestBody SchedulerVO schedulerVO) {
        /**
         * schedulerVO.recurrence is null regardless of whether
         * "recurrence" is absent or "recurrence" is null explicitly
         * in the JSON request body
         */
        return meetingService.patchMeeting(meetingId, schedulerVO);
    }
}
```